# Portable way to list all files in a directory without parsing ls or find

Tags: shell, unix, sh, glob

I'm trying to get a list of all files in a given directory to provide a list of filenames for a simple dotfiles Makefile. The idea is that the list of filenames is put into a variable, and then a list of "meta" files such as the Makefile itself are removed from the list. Then, the files in the list are symlinked into $HOME.

I don't want to [parse ls or find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) because I can't rely on some random program to name its configuration file without whitespace. And I also can't rely on programs to start their "dotfiles" filenames with a "dot".

I tried the for-loop solution at [parse ls or find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), which uses the * glob. The problem is that globs do not by default match files starting with a dot.

There are globbing options in each shell (bash, zsh, etc) that make the * glob expand to include .dotfiles, and even to exclude . and .. But that isn't portable.

Any suggestions?

Let me know if you see an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: "...the list of filenames is put into a variable": this gets you right back the problem of parsing the output of `ls`: what character safely separates two file names in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the glob in two steps, and prune the `.` and `..` entries manually, or with a test for "regular file".  Of course the "echo" is just for testing.  Add it to your list for non-trivial processing.

Edit: Silly me.  Instead of actually looping twice, the list of all files (with and without dots) is just `* .*`.  Also, the test command `[` takes its argument as a string, so we need to quote it for spaces.  Revised code:

```
# Process non-dotfiles and dotfiles.  (Only the regular files)
for f in * .*; do 
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        echo $f 
    fi; 
done
```

Or, use `find` to do the entire job at once, including the symlinking.  For example:

```
find . -type f \( ! -iname Makefile \) -exec ln -s \{\} newdir/\{\} \;
```

Or, use a combination of the two, using `find -print0` pattern as suggested in your source link: that will handle the spaces and the newlines correctly, letting your script get null-separated filenames to store and further process.

Comment: +1 for the find only solution, which is the safe and portable way of doing this.

Comment: Found and fixed a bug in the loop version related to spaces in file name, which goes to show that it's hard to get right.  ;)  I agree with @thatotherguy in recommending "find" as the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> I don't want to parse ls or find because I can't rely on some random program to name its configuration file without whitespace.

The whitespace problem is why `find` has the `-print0` option, to print its output separated by null characters (ASCII 0) that cannot appear in filenames.